# CSS outlook images issues

Tags: html, css, outlook

[image]

My problem is that on the image on the table tr img has a padding on it i cant seem to stretch its width 100% and heigh 100% no padding no margin.

This issues only occurs on outlook i added some css on it like hspace and vspace to 0, and padding 0 and margin 0 and also trying display block and alignment it seems it doesnt work.

Any ideas guys? and also adding `height="100%"` or on `style="height:100%"` it still has a padding and margin on it.
here is the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/jqueryloper/79e0kvet.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) example? Just so we have a better idea of the HTML / CSS being used.

Comment: Would be good if you share whatever you tried so far.

Comment: here is my jsfiddle sorry guys
https://jsfiddle.net/jqueryloper/79e0kvet/

Comment: Please put your [mcve] in the question itself rather than linking to JSFiddle, per the rules. This helps prevent link rot and saves time when trying to debug.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try adding the image as a background of the table-cell, so, assigning the id "imageInside" to the :

```
#imageInside {
  background: #00ff00 url("....") no-repeat fixed; 
}
```

i set a feedle for you, of course it should be tested in Outlook, but it should work.
http://jsfiddle.net/7eob1syL/

Comment: thanks @holden but css background doesnt work on outlook my apologies

Comment: You can combine CSS end VML into your mails, take a look: https://backgrounds.cm/

Comment: sorry but it still doesnt work when i add backgrounds cm it goes on the body bckground image i cant seem to contain it under td background images my apologies

Answer (score 1):

What if you add align="left" in image

```
<img width="100%" height="215" align="left" class="CToWUd" style="margin:0px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" src="https://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/976/media/images/83351000/jpg/_83351965_explorer273lincolnshirewoldssouthpicturebynicholassilkstone.jpg" alt="">
```

will that help you?

Comment: Hi sinisa i add the align left but sorry outlook still not working my apologies

Comment: Hi Mary, no worry at all :) I can not remember if it will work, but try to add display: inline-block or maybe display: inline-table